# Powershell Custom Cmdlet - Call WriteObject in Background Thread

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Calling the WriteObject Method from a background thread is not possible!

Is there a possibility, to invoke/dispatch this method in the main thread of the powershell (like in WPF)?

Code sample:

```
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    base.ProcessRecord();
    ...
    Service.StartReading(filter, list => { WriteObject(list, true); } );
}
```

**EDIT:**
[image: The error, which occured after calling the WriteObject method from the thread]

Any solution, workaround or quick fix?

thx,
Mathias

Comment: The standard System.Console.Out.WriteLine() method works great, but i need to pipe those result objects!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, which solves my problem.

1. created a ConcurrentQueue

   ```
   ConcurrentQueue<LogEntryInfoBase> logEntryQueue = 
           new ConcurrentQueue<LogEntryInfoBase>();
   ```
2. start a background thread to enqueue items to the ConcurrentQueue

   ```
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Service.StartReading(
           filter, EnqueueLogEntryInfoBases));
   ```
3. meanwhile, try to dequeue from this queue in the main thread

   ```
   for ( ; ; )
   {
       LogEntryInfoBase logEntry = null;
       logEntryQueue.TryDequeue(out logEntry);
       if (logEntry != null)
       {
           WriteObject(logEntry);
       }
       Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
   ```

From my point of view, this solution/fix is ugly, but it works for my current issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on pretty much the same issue. In my opinion we can improve the solution by adding a sleep in the infinite loop. Of course we will need to have a global reference to our main thread and the background thread will need to call interrupt as soon as an item is added in queue.

Comment: This answer should be a comment of the answer by SpecialHias, because it is not an answer to the OP's question.